# How to read off a fixing from a swap curve?

Tags: finance, swaps

Let $F_t(T_1, T_2)$ be the forward swap rate at time $t$ from $T_1$ to $T_2$.

Consider a swap that fixes at time $T$, with effective date at time $T + 2D$, and payment date 6 months later at $T + 2D + 6M$.

That is, the swap fixes two days prior to being effective.

My question is, which of the following determines the fixing for the swap payment that occurs at $T + 2D + 6M$?

$$A:=     F_T(T, T + F)$$
or
$$B:=         F_T(T + 2D, T + 2D + F)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is B.

Generally speaking the notation refers to swaps or rates defined by their ***effective date***.

In EUR a swap that is effective T+2 and finishes T+2+f is will have its fixing  determined at time T.

In GBP a swap that is effective T+2 and finished T+2+F will have its fixing determined at time T+2 (since there was no LIBOR lag in GBP when it existed).